# Trying to pull out last id from a table and group by a specific column

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10, cfml, coldfusion-2016

It only gives me one record, i dont know whats the problem, if i just loop the whole query then it works

```
<cfquery name="messages_tb" datasource="appdb">
    SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE receiver = <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
    and rt = <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint">
    group by sender
</cfquery>

<cfset list.messages_tb_sender = ValueList(messages_tb.sender)>

<cfquery name="messages_tb" datasource="appdb">
    SELECT * FROM messages
    WHERE sender IN ( <cfqueryparam value="#list.messages_tb_sender#" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer" list="yes">)
    group BY mid
</cfquery>

<cfoutput>
    #messages_tb.mid#
</cfoutput>
```

and this is how the table looks

```
mid    sender   receiver  message
======|=======|==========|=============
1        2         1        Hello
2        2         1        Hey
3        3         1        xyz
4        2         1        random text
```

I want data from only mid no 3 and 4

Comment: You have to loop it.  What you are doing in that code will take the first element in the result set only.  Also do not use select * even if you are receiving all columns.

Comment: As Paul said, your cfoutput is missing the "query" name.  However, your sample data looks wrong because the 2nd query wouldn't return ONLY mid=3 or mid=4.

Comment: This could be written as a single query instead of two + looping.

Comment: 1. The "rt" columns is missing from your sample. Please update the sample to include all of the relevant columns 2. Please provide an example of the actual results AND the *expected* results.

Answer (score 1):

1. If you only need mid no: 3 and 4 data, then the query will be like this...

   ```
   <cfquery name="messages_tb" datasource="appdb">
     SELECT mid, sender, receiver, message FROM messages
     WHERE receiver = <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
     and mid in <cfqueryparam value="3,4" list="yes" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
   </cfquery>
   ```
2. If you need to pull out last id from a table and group by a specific column. I assume mid is unique according to the table output, then we may no need `group by mid`

   ```
   <cfquery name="messages_tb" datasource="appdb">
     select mid, sender, receiver, message FROM messages
     where mid in (
       select top 1 mid from messages
       and receiver = <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
       order by mid desc
       )
   </cfquery>
   ```

FYI: As is see from table output there is no column named **rt**

Answer (score 1):

*(Too long for comments...)*

1. To answer your question, the reason a single value is displayed is because the `cfoutput` is missing a "query" name, as Paul pointed out. Without a query name, cfoutput defaults to displaying the first value - in the first row. If you want to display *all* rows in the query, you must add the "query" attribute.

   ```
   <cfoutput query="messages_tb">
       #messages_tb.mid#
   </cfoutput>
   ```
2. However, you don't need two separate queries. A simple JOIN would return the same results in a single query.

   ```
   SELECT DISTINCT m.Mid
   FROM  messages m INNER JOIN 
         (
           SELECT DISTINCT sender 
           FROM   messages
           WHERE  receiver = <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_integer">
           AND    rt = <cfqueryparam value="1" cfsqltype="cf_sql_tinyint">
         ) s ON s.sender = m.sender
   ```
3. **Having said all that, neither will return ONLY records MID = 3 and 4. So could you please elaborate?**

   **A. What does the "MID" column represent?**
   **B. Why should the query should only return values 3 and 4?**

   Based on your sample data, the 1st query would return:

   ```
   sender
   ======|
   2
   3
   ```

   Since ALL of the sample records have those sender values, your 2nd query would return all 4 records:

   ```
   mid    sender 
   ======|=======|
   1        2    
   2        2    
   3        3    
   4        2
   ```

   **So either your sample data is wrong or something is missing from your current queries.**